# addAttributeToSelect Call to undefined method M2

Tags: magento2, blocks, collection, model, fatal-error

I have two custom modules and am calling one collectionfactory in other module and getting `

> Call to undefined method addAttributeToSelect

Collection file look like

```
    class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource collection
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Hello', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Hello');
    }
}
```

and am calling in block

```
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Hello\CollectionFactory; 

    class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
    {
    public function __construct(
            CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
            array $data = []
        ) {

            $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
            parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
        }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }

    }
```

> Getting PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Hello\Collection::addAttributeToSelect()

Comment: Try `addFieldToSelect('*')`

Comment: Cool, I put it as an answer

Answer (score 9):

You have to replace `addAttributeToSelect('*')` with `addFieldToSelect('*')`

`addAttributeToFilter()` is used to filter **EAV** collections.

`addFieldToFilter()` is used to filter **Non-EAV** collections.

Answer (score 3):

Try with

`$collection->addFieldToSelect('*');`

which is exist under

> \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection

and

`addAttributeToSelect`

method exist under

> \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection

so you need to create module with **EAV**.

Comment: Welcome!! happy to help you Please accept the answer so it will help others.